# Vertical slider with horizontal slides with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a product that has multiple images. on top or bottom click I want to change the product. and on click next and prev I want to change that product images.

this is my HTML format

```
<div class="product" id="1">
    <div class="product_img" id="1_0"><img src=""/></div>
    <div class="product_img" id="1_1"><img src=""/></div>
    <div class="product_img" id="1_2"><img src=""/></div>
</div>
<div class="product" id="2">
    <div class="product_img" id="2_0"><img src=""/></div>
    <div class="product_img" id="2_1"><img src=""/></div>
    <div class="product_img" id="2_2"><img src=""/></div>
</div>
<div class="product" id="3">
    <div class="product_img" id="3_0"><img src=""/></div>
    <div class="product_img" id="3_1"><img src=""/></div>
    <div class="product_img" id="3_2"><img src=""/></div>
</div>
```

[image]

How to implement with JavaScript or jquery?
is there any plugin?
any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: i tried owl carousel js. but it's only provide horizontal slider

Comment: try [Fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/), I've also modified one of their example in codepen to demo this. Link [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JERVaV)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should check out swiper. http://idangero.us/swiper/#.WH0PsrYrKA0.

In the demos you can check out the "nested" slider http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/#.WH0PybYrKA0.

Ive used this in a couple applications. Super slick